# My single page application which is implemented using AngularJS is taking long time to load the page

Tags: javascript, angularjs, performance

I am working on the Single page application and using AngularJS. In my application, all DOM elements get loads using ajax and due to this I have used number of ng-repeat and binding expression and this is the reason my page is taking long time to load the page. Please help to solve my issue.

**app**

```
angular.module('tabApp', []);
```

**Service**

```
angular.module('tabApp')
.service('mrcService', ['$http', function($http) {
    this.categories = [];
    this.getCategories = function() {
        return $http({
            method: "GET",
            url: 'mrcdata.aspx'
        }).success(function(data) {
            categories = data;
            return categories;
        });
    };
}]);
```

**Controller**

```
angular.module('tabApp')
.controller('dynamicContentCtrl', ['$scope', 'mrcService', function($scope, mrcService) {
    $scope.categories = [];
    mrcService.getCategories().then(function(response) {
        $scope.categories = response.data.Categories;
    });
}]);
```

**HTML code**

```
<div class="main-content container" ng-controller="dynamicContentCtrl">
    <div ng-controller="desktopTabCtrl" class="row desktop-content">
            <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 category-items">
              <nav class="nav categories-nav">
                <ul class="categories">
                  <li ng-repeat="category in categories" class="category" ng-class="{ active: isSet(category.CategoryRank) }">
                    <a href="javascript:void(0)" ng-click="setTab(category.CategoryRank)" class="text">
                        <span>{{category.CategoryTitle}}</span>
                    </a>
                    <span class="arrow-right"></span>
                  </li>
                  <li class="category static">
                    <C5:LocalLiteral runat="server" Text="mrc.home.learnmoretab"/>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </nav>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-8 document-tiles">
              <div ng-repeat="category in categories" ng-show="isSet(category.CategoryRank)" class="tile-container">
                <div class="row">
                  <div ng-repeat="document in category.Documents" class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 tile">
                    <div class="tile-content row">
                      <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
                          <div class="thumbNail-content col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                            <p class="title">{{document.DocumentTitle}}</p>
                            <p class="audience">{{document.Audience}}</p>
                          </div>
                          <div class="thumbNail-image col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                            <img alt="Thumb Nail" src="{{document.ThumbnailUrl}}">
                          </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
                        <div class="download-section">
                            <select class="lang-dropdwn" 
                                ng-model="document.DefaultDialectId" 
                                ng-change="selectLang(document , document.LocalizedDocuments , document.DefaultDialectId )">
                                <option ng-repeat="localizedDocument in document.LocalizedDocuments"
                                    value="{{localizedDocument.DialectId}}">
                                    {{localizedDocument.LanguageName}}
                                </option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                        <div class="button-conatiner" ng-init="document.DownloadLink = document.DocumentId +':'+document.DefaultLocalizedDocumentId">
                            <a class="button" href="documentdownloader.aspx?documentid={{document.DownloadLink}}"><C5:LocalLiteral runat="server" Text="basket.esddelivery"/></a>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a few options you can try to improve performance.

**1. You should set the `track by` in the ng-repeats**

> To minimize creation of DOM elements, ngRepeat uses a function to "keep track" of all items in the collection and their corresponding DOM elements. For example, if an item is added to the collection, ngRepeat will know that all other items already have DOM elements, and will not re-render them.
>
> The default tracking function (which tracks items by their identity) does not allow duplicate items in arrays. This is because when there are duplicates, it is not possible to maintain a one-to-one mapping between collection items and DOM elements.
>
> If you do need to repeat duplicate items, you can substitute the default tracking behavior with your own using the track by expression.
>
> For example, you may track items by the index of each item in the collection, using the special scope property $index.

Example:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items track by $index">{{item.name}}</div>
```

**2. You could use one way data binding to items you know wont be changed. This will disable the watchers for those items and improve performance. Example:**

Instead of this

```
{{item.name}}
```

Use this

```
{{::item.name}}
```

Please remember that this is a one way binding and these values will not be updated if something changes in your scope but you will need to manually update it.

**3. Try to limit the `ng-show` and `ng-hide` attributes since this will add more watchers and leads to poor performance.**